# Does a matrix $A$ need to have $\det A \neq 0$ to even have a rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Does a matrix $A$ need to have $\det A \neq 0$ to even have a rank?

So I've had this uneasy feeling that the rank could not be calculated for a matrix $4\times 4$ which had two identical columns, and therefore its determinant was zero. Am I wrong?

Comment: Every matrix has a rank.

Comment: Do you mean to have it's rank equal to order?

Comment: In fact if $\det A \neq 0$ then the rank of the matrix will always be its dimension (4 in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any matrix $A\in M_{m\times n}(\Bbb R)$ defines a linear map $T:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ given by $T(\vec x)=A\vec x$. The **rank** of $A$ is defined to be the dimension of $\DeclareMathOperator{Image}{Image}\Image(T)$.

The point here is that rank is defined for *any* matrix while the determinant is only defined for *square* matrices. So the short answer to your question is no: $A$ need not satisfy $\det A\neq 0$ in order for $\DeclareMathOperator{Rank}{Rank}\Rank(A)$  to be defined.

Of course, knowing $\det(A)$ can give information about $\Rank(A)$. If $A$ is $n\times n$  and $\det(A)\neq0$, then $A$ is *invertible* and $\Rank(A)=n$. Otherwise, if $\det(A)=0$, then $A$ is *not* invertible so $\Rank(A)< n$.

Unfortunately $\det(A)$ does not give us complete information about $\Rank(A)$. For example each of the following matrices
\begin{align*}
X 
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
&
Y 
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
&
Z
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
has determinant $0$ while
\begin{align*}
\Rank(X) &= 0 & \Rank(Y) &= 1 & \Rank (Z) &= 2
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

The rank is the dimension of the range space, which may be zero (if the 
matrix is the zero matrix, for example).

If the matrix has two identical columns, then you know that the rank is at most
$3$.

I am guessing this was not the point of the question, but every matrix has
a rank as defined above, but **computing** the rank numerically can be a delicate
 task.